# Two View components cause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am having a strange problem when I have two view components on my page at the same time. When I have two the database claims their migrations which there is not I believe this is down to a threading issue.

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "RelationShipsList")]
public class RelationShipsViewComponent : ViewComponent {

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    private readonly MISDBContext db;
    public int CaseId { get; set; }
    public RelationShipsViewComponent(MISDBContext context, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) {
        db = context;
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;

    }
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int caseId) {
        

        var items = await GetItemsAsync(caseId);

        _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("CaseId", CaseId.ToString());

        return View(items);
    }

    private Task<List<RelationShips>> GetItemsAsync(int caseId) {
        var test = db.RelationShips.Where(x => x.isAcitve == true && x.MISObjectId == caseId).ToListAsync();
        return db.RelationShips.Where(x => x.isAcitve == true && x.MISObjectId == caseId).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

I Invoke it as such

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("RelationShipsList", new { caseId = Model.Id })
```

I have another view component which is basically looking up a notes table. I believe the issue is maybe invoking them async maybe its not giving one time to finish before it gets to the other.

Error received I have checked there is no migrations due.

> A database operation failed while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context
> before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by
> different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more
> information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913. There are pending
> model changes for MISDBContext In Visual Studio, use the Package
> Manager Console to scaffold a new migration for these changes and
> apply them to the database:
>
> PM> Add-Migration [migration name] PM> Update-Database Alternatively,
> you can scaffold a new migration and apply it from a command prompt at
> your project directory:
>
> > dotnet ef migrations add [migration name]
> > dotnet ef database update

Answer (score 1):

This

```
var test = db.RelationShips.Where(x => x.isAcitve == true && x.MISObjectId == caseId).ToListAsync();
return db.RelationShips.Where(x => x.isAcitve == true && x.MISObjectId == caseId).ToListAsync();
```

Creates two seperate tasks, each one will use the DbContext to query the database.  Just remove the first one.